# Can I embed an interactive game within a fan page?

Tags: facebook-page

Is it possible to embed a game app within an i-frame on a fan page so that the user remains on the fan page for the entire game play period and is not taken outside to a different game app page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can embed almost anything you want as long as it adheres to the Facebook TOS/Policies.